# Using Django to write a iCalendar file, format of file?

Tags: django, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have some data from my website that I would like to manually write to an iCalendar file and then export to Google calendar. Since the rest of my website is in Django, I'd like to do this using Django. What is the format of iCal files? I've Googled but didn't really come up with a very precise definition of the format and header need (especially for recurrent events). Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: official spec http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-dawson-ical-xml-dtd-01, wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#Technical_specifications

Comment: despite dm03514's comment, the official spec of icalendar is rfc5545: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this app https://github.com/statesofpop/django-cal

I've used it for iCal integrations in the past. Great little app and very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [RFC5545 specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5545.txt). [This page](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/) is a little easier to use for understanding particular parameters.

The wikipedia link dm03514 posted is useful for getting a basic calendar format to mimic, but you should also go ahead and make a Google calendar, fill it with some events, and export to see what they use. Some non-standard values like X-WR-CALNAME are widely supported.